# String Variations

Tags: python, string, combinations

I have a string in python and a dictionary of 'rules', or possible alterations to the string. For example, one rule might have a key of `'he'` and a value of `'e'`, or a key of `'ll'` and a value of `'l'`.

These rules would mean that any occurrence of ``'he' in my string can be replaced with an `'e'`, and similarly for `'ll'` and `'l'`.

What I want is to find all variations of my string, given this dictionary of rules. For instance, with the two rules from above and the string `'hello'`, I would like to return:

```
['hello', 'ello', 'helo', 'elo']
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Find all results with rule e=>ee

Comment: @StefanPochmann If that were the only rule, I would expect ['hello', 'heello']. With all three rules, it would be ['hello', 'ello', 'helo', 'elo', 'heello', 'eello', 'heelo', 'eelo'].

Comment: @Clayton @StefanPochmann has a point: If you allow rules to be applied on the outcome of rules, such as `hello -> ello -> eello` in your example, you must consider infinite loops. In your comment, you implicitly presumed that you cannot apply the rule `e -> ee` more than one, otherwise you would end up with infinite results: `hello, heello, heeello, heeeello, ...`.  A similar example can be constructed with multiple rules: `e -> ef, f -> e`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a recursive function that takes a substring of the input.  This function then examines all rules.  For each rule that matches, one replacement is done, and the remainder of the string is processed by a recursive call:

```
def apply_rules(rules, input, start=0):
    # First yield the outcome of no applied rules.
    yield input[start:]

    for match, replace in rules:
        # Find the first match for this rule.
        index = input.find(match, start)
        if index < 0:
            # No match -- skip to next one
            continue
        # Prepare the result of the replacement.
        prefix = input[start:index] + replace
        # Apply further rules to the rest of the string
        # by a recursive call.
        for suffix in apply_rules(rules, input, index + len(match)):
            yield prefix + suffix
```

Use it like this:

```
>>> rules = [('he','e'), ('ll','l'), ('e','ee')]
>>> list(apply_rules(rules, 'hello'))
['hello', 'ello', 'elo', 'helo', 'heello', 'heelo']
```

Please note that I don't allow rules to be applied on replaced strings, to prevent cases of infinite results as demonstrated in the comments to this question.

Comment: you might want to rework the first `for` with `for match, replace in rules.items()`

Comment: @Pynchia My `apply_rules` happens to expect a sequence of pairs to represent the rules, I leave it up to the reader to adapt for different representations, such as dictionaries.